# Set Operation to be only Soap not Rest, when have two endpoint

Tags: wcf, session, rest

It os a way to force Operation to be only SOAP. I have two endpoints in config - SOAP and REST and now every Operation is supported by both.

My main problem is that I want to use sessios in my one Operation but now when I enable it wcf fire error that my operation not support session cause it is also REST :/

Comment: It is hard to understand the actual question you have. Can you try adding some configuration and code examples to clearify?

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is no such possibility for forcing it to be either rest or something when you have multiple endpoints . One of the possible ways is to make use of two service tags with different base URI though I'm not sure if it would work